# How can I generate PDF invoice in my LightSwitch desktop application?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to generate PDF invoice from my LightSwitch application.

How can I do that ?

I want to provide standard PDF Invoice format with multiple items in grid and Logo on top with customer information & other details.

Answer (score 2):

Lightswitch doesn't include a reporting engine.  I suggest you take a look at SSRS or Crystal reports.